# jQuery ajax call is not firing as a json call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a jQuery call like this, which gives me a lot of problems:

```
  $('#submit').click(function () {
        var url = "/home/start";
        var notifyEmail = $("#notify_email").val();
        var receiverPhone = $("#receiver_phone").val();
        var sliderValue = $("#slider").slider("value");

        var dataToSend = '{phoneReceiver:' + receiverPhone + ', emailNotify:' + notifyEmail + ', value:' + sliderValue + '}';
        //var dataToSend = '{"phoneReceiver":"' + receiverPhone + '", "emailNotify":"' + notifyEmail + '", "value:"' + sliderValue + '"}';

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: dataToSend,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert('Awesome destination: ' + data.DestinationAddress);

            },
            error: function (date) {
                alert('An occurred while purchasing. Please try again later');
            }
        });
    });
```

I've tried fiddling with the data formatting (as you can see there are two versions) and with/without dataType and contentType. No luck yet.

I have the following problems:

- I get an 500 Internal server error, which looks like formatting errors
- The call is not made as json in FireBug. When selecting the json tab there is nothing, but the post has

Because of this, my breakpoint inside the webservice, is never hit.

All the parameters in the data is fine.

In FireBug, I can see my post is:

```
{phoneReceiver:fgsdfg, emailNotify:dgsg, value:19}
```

Or:

```
{"phoneReceiver":"gfjhfghj", "emailNotify":"fjhfgjhgj", "value:"16"}
```

Any hints?

Comment: `dataType` is the expected type of the **return** data. The problem is on the server hence the 500

Comment: Which I guess is a problem with how I format my data.. Any ideas? Thanks :-)

Comment: It's how you're handling a request on the server that's the first problem you need to fix. The current question title is unlikely to get you answers to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get your code working as follows:

```
    //action
    [HttpPost]
    public void TestAction(string phoneReceiver, string emailNotify, int value)
    {
        //all variables set here
    }


    //in view i have a button id = submit
    $('#submit').click(function () {
            var dataToSend = '{phoneReceiver: "blah", emailNotify:"blah@blah.com", value: 1}';

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/TestController/TestAction',
                data: dataToSend,
                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('Awesome destination: ' + data.DestinationAddress);

                },
                error: function (date) {
                    alert('An occurred while purchasing. Please try again later');
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: @LarsHoldgaard can you tell us what you were missing ? was it `[HttpPost]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: { phoneReceiver: receiverPhone, emailNotify: notifyEmail,  value: sliderValue},
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Awesome destination: ' + data.DestinationAddress);

        },
        error: function (date) {
            alert('An occurred while purchasing. Please try again later');
        }
    });
```

Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sending a JSON back try creating the dataToSend object as

```
    var dataToSend = {
           phoneReceiver: $("#receiver_phone").val(),
           emailNotify :$("#notify_email").val()
           value: $("#slider").slider("value")
    };
```